# input of Auto-Encoder as a feature extraction for training is similar to data that we use later for a classification model?

Tags: classification, autoencoder

I have a data set of images, for example, 200 images, I want to use Autoencoder as a feature compressor. I use for example 150 for train the autoencoder and 50 for evaluation. after train and evaluate my Autoencoder, I save the encoder part. then I develop a classification model, for example, SVM or ..., I wat use encoder as a compressor before SVM, I have just those previous 200 images, should I use them again as input of the encoder and use compressed version as input of SVM? I mean is it possible to have the same input in the training phase of an autoencoder and then when I want to use the encoder part as compressor previous of a classification model?